# Setting IAM role for Lambda after login with Cognito on iOS

Tags: swift, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I'm getting a trouble when trying to connect AWSCognito to AWSLambda to pass an Auth role into it. My application has serverless architecture based on CognitoUserPool's, Lambda and IAM. So I have one configuration for all these things like the following:

```
    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(
        regionType: CognitoIdentityUserPoolRegion,
        identityPoolId: CognitoIdentityUserPoolIdentityId,
        identityProviderManager: nil
    )

    // setup service configuration
    let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
         region: CognitoIdentityUserPoolRegion, 
         credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider
    )

    // create pool configuration
    let poolConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientId,
                                                                    clientSecret: nil,
                                                                    poolId: CognitoIdentityUserPoolId)

    // initialize user pool client
    AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.register(with: serviceConfiguration, userPoolConfiguration: poolConfiguration, forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)

    // fetch the user pool client we initialized in above step
    let pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)
    pool.delegate = self

    AWSLambdaInvoker.register(with: serviceConfiguration!, forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)
```

Then I do log in using the following snippet:

```
     func signIn(username: String, password: String) -> Promise<Bool> {
        let user = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey).getUser()
        return Promise(resolvers: { resolve, reject in
         user.getSession(username, password: password, validationData: nil)
            .continueWith(block: { task -> Any? in
      if let error = task.error {
        let message = (error as NSError).userInfo["message"] as? String
        return reject(AWSError.SignIn.sessionError(message))
      }
      guard let idToken = task.result?.idToken?.tokenString else {
        return reject(AWSError.SignIn.noTokenProvided)
      }
      guard let identityId = user.username else {
        return reject(AWSError.SignIn.noIdentityIdProvided)
      }
      return resolve(true)
    })
  })
}
```

The issue is that I'm always getting an error saying that:

> User:
>   arn:aws:sts:{identity}:assumed-role/**Cognito_myUnauth_Role**/CognitoIdentityCredentials
>   is not authorized to perform: InvokeLambda

I tested an official example, I wrote my own implementations, and also I tried all the solutions mentioned in this thread: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/357 , but there was no luck with it.

I also tried implementing my own `AWSCognitoCredentialsProviderHelper` but the error is still presented. Do you have any ideas or maybe you also have faced with this issue so you can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Does the role policy allows it to perform Lambda Invocation? Can you post the roles policies?